# C program runs wrongly in VS code

Tags: c

I'm trying to find whether a number is armstrong number or not using C program. The code works fine when I run in online compiler, but gives a wrong output in vs code. What could be the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(){
    int n,a,digit=0,res,b,sum=0;
    printf("Enter a number ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int copy1=n;
    int copy2=n;
    while(n!=0){
        a=n%10;
        n=n/10;
        digit++;
    }
    printf("Digits: %d\n", digit);
    while(copy1!=0){
        b=copy1%10;
        printf("b- %d ",b);
        res=(int)pow(b,digit);
        printf("res- %d\n",res);
        sum=sum+res;
        copy1=copy1/10;
    }
    if(sum==copy2){
        printf("%d is an armstrong number",copy2);
    }
    else{
        printf("%d is not an armstrong number",copy2);
    }
}
```

Wrong output given by vs code
[image: vscode output ss]

Output given by online compiler
[image: online compiler output ss]

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Post text as properly formatted text. You can [edit] your question. Also read this: [ask]

Comment: Don't use the floating-point `pow` function for integer functions. Create your own instead.

Comment: Why didn't you post your actual question _Why does `(int)pow(3,5)` yield 124 on one platform and 125 on the other_? The whole Armstrong number stuff is just useless clutter,

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Is the right answer! Some implementations of `pow` tend to undershoot the intergral result. In my not so humble opinion, an implementation of `pow` that doesn't recover the correct integral value for integral arguments ought to be considered defective. The old-fashioned way of evaluating `pow(x, y)` is `exp(y * log(x))` and that that tends to undershoot.

Comment: @Jabberwocky - Given the state of the code and vague question, it’s likely OP didn’t realise this was the cause of the issue.  (Happy to be corrected by OP here.)

Comment: Next time you get a problem like this, please learn how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. If you used a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values, you would have been able to quickly see where the problem occurs. And from that you could create a truly small [mre] if you still could not solve it.

Comment: @s3dev well, he actually did print the result of `pow` in his output...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude he did debug his code (using  printf) and obviously the result of pow was 124 vs. 125

Comment: @Jabberwocky - Yes, agreed.  (“ … obvious to some …”)

Comment: @SAI - Out of curiosity, what is the result if you miss out VSC (and all that mess), and compile and run directly in the terminal (of your local machine)?

Comment: As others have suggested.  Replace the `pow` call with this: `res = 1; for (int p = 0; p < digit; p++) {res = res * b;}`

Comment: @s3dev why should that change anything?

Comment: @s3dev I actually run the code in VS Code's integrated terminal...

Comment: I just wanna know why it works fine in an online compiler and not in VSC

Comment: @SAI - That’s my question (but vaguely stated).  Do you get a different answer when *not* running in VSC, but on your core OS.  My curiosity is, ‘is it an issue isolated inside VSC?’ Manually compile it and run in your terminal, completely separate from VSC.

Comment: @selbie when I use res = 1; for (int p = 0; p < digit; p++) {res = res * b;} instead of pow, it works fine in VS Code.

Comment: (int)(pow(3,5)+0.5) would sort it out if he must use pow() that way. I'd hazard a guess that one implementation recognises pow(int,int) and optimises it to integer multiplies. Likewise some compilers special case pow(any, 0.5) as sqrt(). Intel's compiler will also optimise pow(double,1.0/3.0) to system cbrt() which can be confusing because it gets amazingly good accuracy that way.

Comment: I'm closing this question down as an exact duplicate of several other questions. `pow` is notoriously inaccurate on various platforms. Not just because of floating point rounding, but also because the function itself is often implemented to favor speed over accuracy. Both these cases can sway the predictability of using `pow` for simple exponent math on integers. I any case, there's at least a half-dozen exact duplicates of this question on StackOverflow, if not more.